# console.log not working in chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Google Chrome Extension. 
The console.log doesn't work in the addListener, however works fine outside addListener. I have reinstalled. I have tried this on Windows and MacOS.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(

 function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    console.log("listen"); // this does not
    alert("got here"); // this works


 }
);
```

Comment: Did you send a message?

Comment: I just edited the original example. The alert does work, but the console.log does not.

Comment: Where is this code? Where are you viewing the log?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the code is in your background this `console.log` doesn't appear in the log of the current page. Look like that is the case.

If that is the case:

Go to `chrome://extensions/` look for your extension.
Click on `Inspect views: background.html` (you can have another name depending of you manifest). You will see a developer tool with the a console.

Comment: Thank you this is the solution! I thought the console log was it. I guess there is no way to watch both logs at the same time?

Comment: You can see both the browser and background logs.